# PhoneFactor Technical Profile

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, policy

Is it possible to change the OTP length, expiration time for OTP in phone factor technical profile via custom policy?

What is the metadata name in such case?

Comment: Any inputs please.

Comment: Have you checked this sample: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-sms-displaycontrol

Comment: The link explains usage of custom provider for sending SMS. However, my use case is different. I am using the technical profile 'PhoneFactor' to send the SMS(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/phone-factor-technical-profile#:~:text=In%20this%20article&text=Azure%20Active%20Directory%20B2C%20(Azure,to%20validate%20the%20phone%20number.). I want to set the length of OTP to 5 characters instead of 6. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the SMS OTP properties with the phone factor technical profile nor the SSPR technical profiles. Only if you use the OTP technical profile and a custom OTP delivery mechanism, then you can adjust OTP expiry, length, character set.